# Retrofit keeping threads from being destroyed

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I'm running a standalone kotlin application that consumes a REST api using Retrofit. After all coroutines have finished and the end of the main thread is reached. I get this exception, I'm running the main class from the command prompt using maven

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[Okio Watchdog,5,com.divae.gitlab.MainKt] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 5 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=com.divae.gitlab.MainKt,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy (ThreadGroup.java:795)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

This is how I instantiate the Retrofit instance and OKHttpClient:

```
val connectionPool = ConnectionPool(5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
val okhttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectionPool(connectionPool)
        .addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor(privateToken))
        .build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okhttpClient)
        .build()
```

I've tried all of these but nothing works:

```
okhttpClient.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown()
okhttpClient.dispatcher().cancelAll()
okhttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll()
okhttpClient.cache()?.close()
```

I'm using retrofit2 version 2.9.0